# Check that string contains a character from set of characters

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I need to check the complexity of a password. One of the conditions is that the password must contain at least one number. I've tried the following approach but it does not give me expected results and I don't know what's wrong.

```
NSString *regexpNumbers = @"[0-9]+";
NSPredicate *predicateNumbers = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@", regexpNumbers];
result &= [predicateNumbers evaluateWithObject:password];
```

evaluateWithObject: method returns NO even if the password contains some number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using `rangeOfCharacterFromSet`:**

You can create your own character set like the way:

```
NSCharacterSet *s = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_"];
s = [s invertedSet];

NSString *string = @"String to find";
NSRange r = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:s];
if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"the string contains illegal characters");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Found!!!");
}
```

**Using `NSPredicate`:**

```
NSString *myRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z_]*"; 
NSPredicate *myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", myRegex]; 
NSString *string = @"String to find";
BOOL valid = [myTest evaluateWithObject:string];
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

When using `NSPredicate` with regex you need to use `MATCHES`, not `CONTAINS` (which is used for direct literal comparison).

Arguably you should't be doing this though. There is an argument that it should be done on the server.

Instead of using regex you could also look to use `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` and `NSCharacterSet` for each of your checks.

Comment: In my opinion, you do this on the server and the client.

Comment: We are doing this check on both - the server and the client. I also had tried using MATCHES before but the problem is that predicate with MATCHES returns NO when the password contains anything else than numbers. It seems that matches does its job on the whole input string regardless ^ and $ in the regex.